# Java regex logical OR

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match any or all from a set of phrases in a given string. Here is my regex:

```
(^|\\W)(" + phrase1 + "|" + phrase2 + "|" + phrase3 + ... ")(\\W|$)
```

I need to be able to match any number of the phrases I am `OR`ing. It seems to work okay except when two phrases occur immediately next to each other. So `"phrase1 lorem ipsum phrase2 lorem ipsum"` matches both phrase1 and phrase2 but `"phrase1 phrase2 lorem ipsum"` matches only phrase1 (so does `"phrase1.phrase2 lorem ipsum"`). If there is more than one non-word character (e.g., two or more spaces) between phrase1 and phrase2 then it matches both as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `\\W` at both sides of your regexp. That is, the first non-word character is matched by the first match, then the second match requires one more non-word character.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect you're after is this:

```
List<String> findPhrases(String s, String... phrases) {
  return findPhrases(s, Arrays.asList(phrases));
}

List<String> findPhrases(String s, Collection<String> phrases) {
  if (phrases.size() < 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("must specify at least one phrase");
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Iterator<String> iter = phrases.iterator();
  String first = iter.next();
  sb.append(first);
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    sb.append("|");
    sb.append(iter.next());
  }
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(" + sb.toString() + ")\\b");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (m.find()) {
    ret.append(Pattern.quote(m.group(1)));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

One important difference here is that I've used \b rather than \W to delimit words. \b is a zero-width match to the start of the string, the end of the string or the transition from a word character to a non-word character of vice versa.

Zero-width means it doesn't consume a character from the input like \W does.

**Edit:** you seem to have two problems:

1. \W is consuming characters from your input; and
2. You have regex special characters in your phrases.

(1) can be handled several ways. My approach above is to use \b instead as it is zero-width and is a much better solution. You can also use other zero-width assertions like lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
<?<=\W|^)...(?=\W|$)
```

but that's basically equivalent to:

```
\b...\b
```

which is far easier to read.

(2) can be handled by quoting phrases. I've amended the above code to call `Pattern.quote()` to quote any regex special characters.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was doing. But it caused a problem if the phrase contained a parenthesis at the beginning or end. Thats is why I used \W instead.

Comment: If the phrase contains a parenthesis then you need to define exactly what a phrase is and what delimits them.

Comment: `\b...\b` does not work even after escaping any special chars in the phrase. Here is my updated regex which seems to work `"(^|\\b|\\W)(" + ORedPhrases + ")(\\W|$)"`

Comment: Why don't you escape the parenthesis?